# Generate block Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I have this verilog code that works like intended and synthesizes on Xilinx with no problems, and runs as intended as a part of a bigger system on a Spartan 7 (Arty S-7 FPGA). However I had to *hardcode* some conditions since I was not able to generate them correctly using the generate block. Those conditions are placed in the else and are the two ifs inside it (compairing the cpt/2). I have comented that block out. By that I am guessing that when the generate block was generating those lines it was not placing them inside the else condition in my always block.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module acc #(
    parameter data_size = 8,
    parameter array_size = 3
) (
    input clk,
    input en,
    input wire [0:(data_size * array_size)-1] from_array, // all lines of the systolic array
    output wire [0:data_size-1] conv // The final result on a discrete convolution 
);
    localparam shift_reg_size = (((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1) * data_size);
    reg [0:$clog2(((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)*2)-1] cpt = 0;
    reg [0:shift_reg_size - 1] shift = 0;
    reg [0:(data_size * array_size)-1] shift_mem = 0;
    reg [0:data_size-1] conv_ = 0;
    assign conv = conv_;

    localparam add_state = 0;
    localparam shift_state = 1;
    reg state = shift_state;

    // genvar i;
    // generate
    //     for (i = 1; i < array_size; i = i + 1) begin : shift_gen
    //         always @(posedge clk) begin  : shift_gen_level
    //             localparam j = ((i-1)*2+1);
    //             if (en && cpt/2 > j && state == add_state && state != shift_state) begin
    //                 shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[i*data_size:(i+1)*data_size-1];
    //             end
    //         end  
    //     end
    // endgenerate
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (en) begin
            if (state == shift_state && state != add_state) begin
                shift_mem <= from_array;
                state <= add_state;
                shift <= {shift_mem[0:data_size-1],shift[0:shift_reg_size - data_size - 1]};  
            end
            else begin
                state <= shift_state;
                if (cpt/2 > 1) begin
                    shift[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1];
                end
                if (cpt/2 > 3) begin
                    shift[3*data_size:(3+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[3*data_size:(3+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[2*data_size:(2+1)*data_size-1];
                end
            end
            cpt <= cpt == {{1'b1},{($clog2(((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)*2)-1){1'b0}}} ? cpt : cpt + 1;
            conv_ <= shift[shift_reg_size - data_size : shift_reg_size - 1];
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Is there a way to rewrite my generate so that I do not have to hardcode the values for each possible configuration of the parameter **array_size** ? Or could I *indicate* to my generate block that I want the resulting code to be placed inside the else condition?

**EDIT**

My original question seemed to lack sufficient detail to be debugged, I will provide more below. I need to generate, depending on the array_size parameter some logic that will execute only on posedge and only when the **state** register is equal to **add_state**. The weird if condition came from there. This additional logic has a condition itself, it must trigger only when **cpt** has reached a certain value, hence the cpt/2 > j.

The current generate block as it is actually generates the correct logic for the simulation, but when building on xilinx I get a multidriven net, because the compiler does not understand that the generated logic is supposed to be in the **else**.

I have changed my code a little adding a case statement to make it more clear to read.
Here is the modified always block, the rest is the same:

```
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (en) begin
            case (state)
                shift_state: 
                begin
                    shift_mem <= from_array;
                    state <= add_state;
                    shift <= {shift_mem[0:data_size-1],shift[0:shift_reg_size - data_size - 1]};  
                end
                add_state: 
                begin
                    state <= shift_state;
                    if (cpt/2 > 1) begin
                        shift[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1];
                    end
                    if (cpt/2 > 3) begin
                        shift[3*data_size:(3+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[3*data_size:(3+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[2*data_size:(2+1)*data_size-1];
                    end
                end
                default: state <= shift_state;
            endcase
            cpt <= cpt == {{1'b1},{($clog2(((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)*2)-1){1'b0}}} ? cpt : cpt + 1;
            conv_ <= shift[shift_reg_size - data_size : shift_reg_size - 1];
        end
    end
```

In other words what I need is that instead of

```
                if (cpt/2 > 1) begin
                    shift[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[1*data_size:(1+1)*data_size-1];
                end
                if (cpt/2 > 3) begin
                    shift[3*data_size:(3+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[3*data_size:(3+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[2*data_size:(2+1)*data_size-1];
                end
```

In my else condition, I will get the dynamically generated code.

Many thanks

Comment: this does not make much sense: `if (state == shift_state && state != add_state)` . The rest needs a non-commented-out example in a form you wanted it and an issue must be described precisely. Currently commented and non-commented parts are very different and cannot be compared.

Comment: I have edited my question, with more explanation. Maybe it will be clearer to understand hat I currently need

Answer (score 0):

The commented out 'generate' code should not cause any multiply driven messages. Bits of *shift* driven by it do not overlap. However they overlap with other stages of the state machine you provided: `shift <= {shift_mem[...`. And the reason all are driven from different always blocks.

One way of solving this would be introduction of a dynamic *for*-loop inside of the always block. However, it will probably cause generation of latches or memories in synthesis for *shift*. I do not think that this is a desirable outcome. S

So, the only way around using generate blocks in your case is to introduce a temporary variable (tmp_shift):

```
  reg [0:shift_reg_size - 1] shift = 0, tmp_shift = 0;
```

And use it in the generate block

```
    genvar i;
    for (i = 1; i < array_size; i = i + 1) begin : shift_gen
         always @(posedge clk) begin  : shift_gen_level
             localparam j = ((i-1)*2+1);
             if (en && cpt/2 > j && state == add_state && state != shift_state) begin
                 // use tmp_shift here:
                 tmp_shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[i*data_size:(i+1)*data_size-1];
                 // these are to preserve other bits in the shift
                 tmp_shift[0:j*data_size-1] <= shift[0:j*data_size-1];
                 tmp_shift[(j+1)*data_size: shift_reg_size - 1] <= shift[(j+1)*data_size: shift_reg_size - 1];
             end
         end  
     end
```

Note that *generate*/*endgenerate* keywords are optional.

Now you can write your stat machine part as the following:

```
           case (state)
                shift_state: 
                begin
                    shift_mem <= from_array;
                    state <= add_state;
                    shift <= {shift_mem[0:data_size-1],shift[0:shift_reg_size - data_size - 1]};  
                end
                add_state: 
                begin
                    state <= shift_state;
                    shift <= tmp_shift; // <<< use tmp_shift here. 
                end
                default: state <= shift_state;
            endcase
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sadly this does not work... That is because whilts writing some of the new values into tmp_shift, some old ones get overwriteen and when using my "hardcoded" version they do not

Comment: I added a couple of statements to generate, which I believe, should fix your other bit override issue.  You can have this solved differently, e.g., using assignment masks and/or checking for boundaries.